# QT designer background image issue

Tags: c++, qt, qt-designer, qtgui

I am trying to insert an background image to central widget.

My way:
Right click on 'centralwidget' -> Change styleSheet -> "background-image: url(:/Resources/bg4.jpg);"

BUT it is applied on each children of central widget.

What the solution of this problem?
(I am don't want to do it via code - only via QT designer)

Thank you for your attention!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the ID-selector of Qt stylesheets to apply the stylesheet just to this instance with this id (object name).

```
QWidget#centralwidget
{
    background-image: url(:/Resources/bg4.jpg);
}
```

With this, you should give your central widget the id/objectname "centralwidget".

You can read more about the Qt Stylesheet syntax [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html).